# Скрипт не работает с русским языком в мозиле

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Всем привет. Есть скрипт который я установила, но проблема в том что он отказывается работать как надо в мозиле. Проблема с русским языком т.е. с английским работает как надо а с русским в мозиле никак не хочет работать - я не могу понять в чем причина. Помогите, пожалуйста.

> @glorain It uses RegExp to look for words, and more concretely it relies on RegExp Unicode Property Escapes, which is not supported in FireFox. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes

```js
const isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
const isSafari = /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor);

const copy = document.querySelector("#copy");
const clear = document.querySelector("#clear");
const spellcheck = document.querySelector("#spellcheck");
const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
const highlights = document.querySelector("#highlights");
const length = document.querySelector("#length");
const output = document.querySelector("output");
const list = document.querySelector("#list");
const template = document.querySelector("template");

let hiddens = [];
let duplicates = {};

// Text analysis
const count = (text, minLength) => {
  // https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es-unicode-property-escapes#word
  const wordRegex = isChrome || isSafari
  ? new RegExp(`([\\p{Alphabetic}\\p{Mark}\\p{Decimal_Number}\\p{Connector_Punctuation}\\p{Join_Control}]+){${minLength},}`, 'gu')
  : new RegExp(`(\\w+){${minLength},}`, 'g');
  let result;
  const words = {};
  while ((result = wordRegex.exec(text)) !== null) {
    const word = result[0].toLowerCase();
    if (!words[word]) {
      words[word] = [];
    }
    words[word].push(result.index);
    words[word].push(result.index + word.length);
  }
  return words;
};

// Array manipulation
const duplicatePass = ([key, value]) => 2 < value.length;

const occurrenceComparator = ([keyA, valueA], [keyB, valueB]) =>
  valueB.length - valueA.length;

const numberComparator = (numberA, numberB) => numberA - numberB;

const differ = (object, [key, value], index) => {
  object[key] = {
    action: object[key] ? "KEEP" : "ADD",
    word: key,
    occurrences: value,
    index
  };
  return object;
};

const cleaner = (object, [word, details]) => {
  if (details.action) {
    delete details.action;
    object[word] = details;
  }
  return object;
};

const flattener = (array, details) => [...array, ...details.occurrences];

// DOM manipulation
const update = (item, details) => {
  item.style.zIndex = details.occurrences.length / 2;
  item.style.top = `${0.6 + details.index * 3}rem`;
  item.querySelector(".count").textContent = details.occurrences.length / 2;
};

const add = (word, details) => {
  const node = document.importNode(template.content, true);
  list.appendChild(node);
  const item = list.lastElementChild;
  item.id = `word-${word}`;
  const hidden = item.querySelector(".hidden");
  hidden.name = word;
  hidden.checked = hiddens.includes(word);
  hidden.addEventListener("change", handleToggle);
  item.querySelector(".word").textContent = word;
  update(item, details);
};

const keep = (word, details) => {
  const item = document.querySelector(`#word-${word}`);
  update(item, details);
};

const markObsolete = word => {
  document.querySelector(`#word-${word}`).classList.add("obsolete");
};

const remove = item => item.remove();

const removeObsolete = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".obsolete").forEach(remove);
};

const render = ([word, details]) => {
  if (details.action === "ADD") {
    add(word, details);
  } else if (details.action === "KEEP") {
    keep(word, details);
  } else {
    markObsolete(word);
  }
};

const getHue = word => {
  return (
    360 -
    360 / Object.keys(duplicates).length * duplicates[word.toLowerCase()].index
  );
};

const getHSL = word => {
  const hue = getHue(word);
  return `hsl(${hue + 20}, 100%, ${180 < hue && hue < 360 ? 80 : 50}%)`;
};

const colorize = word => {
  const color = getHSL(word);
  const count = document.querySelector(`#word-${word} .count`);
  const wordElement = document.querySelector(`#word-${word} .word`);
  count.style.borderColor = color;
  count.style.backgroundColor = color;
  wordElement.style.borderColor = color;
  wordElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
};

const highlight = (occurrence, index, occurrences) => {
  let node;
  if (index < occurrences.length - 1) {
    if (index % 2) {
      const word = textarea.value.substring(occurrence, occurrences[index + 1]);
      node = document.createElement("mark");
      node.textContent = word;
      if (!hiddens.includes(word.toLowerCase())) {
        const color = getHSL(word);
        node.style.background = color;
        node.style.border = `0.2rem solid ${color}`;
      }
    } else {
      const text = textarea.value.substring(occurrence, occurrences[index + 1]);
      node = document.createTextNode(text);
    }
  } else {
    const text = textarea.value.substring(occurrence);
    node = document.createTextNode(text + "\r\n\r\n");
  }
  highlights.appendChild(node);
};

const handleChange = () => {
  // Count words
  const words = count(textarea.value, length.value);

  // Diff word stats with previous
  const diff = Object.entries(words)
    .filter(duplicatePass)
    .sort(occurrenceComparator)
    .reduce(differ, duplicates);

  // Render items
  Object.entries(diff).forEach(render);

  // Clean obsolete from duplicates
  duplicates = Object.entries(diff).reduce(cleaner, {});

  // Adjust height of list
  list.style.height = `${1.2 + Object.keys(duplicates).length * 3}rem`;

  // Colorize items
  Object.keys(duplicates).forEach(colorize);

  // Flatten occurrences
  const occurrences = Object.values(duplicates)
    .reduce(flattener, [0])
    .sort(numberComparator);

  // Highlight
  while (highlights.firstChild) {
    highlights.removeChild(highlights.firstChild);
  }
  occurrences.forEach(highlight);

  // Remove
  window.setTimeout(removeObsolete, 400);
};

const handleToggle = event => {
  const word = event.target.name;
  if (event.target.checked) {
    if (!hiddens.includes(word)) {
      hiddens.push(word);
    }
  } else {
    const index = hiddens.indexOf(word);
    if (0 <= index) {
      hiddens.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
  handleChange();
};

copy.addEventListener("click", () => {
  textarea.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
});

clear.addEventListener("click", () => {
  textarea.value = "";
  textarea.focus();
  handleChange();
});

spellcheck.addEventListener("change", event => {
  textarea.setAttribute("spellcheck", event.target.checked.toString());
  const { value } = textarea;
  textarea.value = value + " ";
  textarea.value = value;
});

textarea.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
  highlights.scrollTop = event.target.scrollTop;
});

textarea.addEventListener(
  "focus",
  () => {
    textarea.value = "";
    handleChange();
  },
  {
    once: true
  }
);

textarea.addEventListener("input", handleChange);
length.addEventListener("input", handleChange);
length.addEventListener("input", () => (output.textContent = length.value));

handleChange();
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  padding: 1.2rem 2.4rem;
  background-color: #2196f3;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4.8rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 0 1.2rem;
}

button {
  margin: 0 12px;
}

#actions {
  flex: 3 0 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1.2rem;
}

#actions > label {
  margin-right: 0.6rem;
}

#options {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  padding: 1.2rem;
  min-width: 20rem;
}

#options > label {
  width: 100%;
}

hr {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

mark {
  margin: -0.2rem;
  border: 0.2rem solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
}

#text {
  position: relative;
  flex: 3 0 0;
  padding: 0 1.2rem;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}

textarea,
#highlights {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: solid 0.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  padding: 1.3rem;
  font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 2rem;
  outline: none;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}

textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% - 2.4rem);
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  resize: none;
}

textarea:focus {
  border: solid 0.2rem #2196f3;
  padding: 1.2rem;
}

#highlights {
  z-index: -1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% - 2.4rem);
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: transparent;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#list {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  padding: 0 1.2rem;
  min-width: 20rem;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 24rem);
  transition: height 0.3s;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  transition: top 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  animation: add 0.3s;
}

.item > label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.count,
.word {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 0.2rem;
  box-shadow: inset 20rem 2rem transparent;
  transition: border 0.3s, background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.hidden:checked ~ .count,
.hidden:checked ~ .word {
  box-shadow: inset 20rem 2rem white;
}

.count {
  border-radius: 50%;
  min-width: 1.8rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
}

.word {
  padding: 0 0.2rem;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.obsolete {
  opacity: 0;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 1.2rem;
  padding: 2.4rem 3.6rem;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

footer > div:last-child {
  text-align: end;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@keyframes add {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Duplicate Word Finder</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <div id="actions">
    <div>
      <button id="copy" class="pure-material-button-contained">Copy</button>
      <button id="clear" class="pure-material-button-text">Clear</button>
    </div>
    <label class="pure-material-switch">
            <input id="spellcheck" type="checkbox" checked>
            <span>Spell Check</span>
        </label>
  </div>
  <div id="options">
    <label class="pure-material-slider">
      <input id="length" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="4">
      <span>Minimum Word Length: <output>4</output></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div id="text">
    <textarea>
Paste your text by pressing Ctrl+V or ⌘+V. (Once you click here, these instructions will be cleared for your convenience ;)

The slider on the top right can be used to adjust the minimum length of words to detect. The default setting is 4, so words like 'and', 'for', 'the', etc. won't pollute the analysis. The duplicate words can be found below the slider highlighted by various colors. The list is sorted by the number of occurrence starting with the highest. The highlighting for any individual word can be turned off by clicking on the word in the list.

You can edit your text here, duplicates are detected real time. When you're finished editing, you can copy or clear the result using the corresponding buttons. You can also turn off the spell checker if you don't need it.

~~~

I often find myself sending emails and messages consisting of two or three sentences. This is where I usually commit an unintentional word repetition, but only realize it after hitting send. This tool comes handy for such cases, and you're free to use it for your benefit as well! :)
</textarea>
    <div id="highlights"></div>
  </div>
  <ol id="list"></ol>
</main>
<footer>
  <div>
    Created by Bence Szabó (finnhvman)<br/>
    <br/>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/finnhvman" target="_top">Twitter</a> &nbsp; | &nbsp;
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/finnhvman/" target="_top">LinkedIn</a> &nbsp; | &nbsp;
    <a href="https://codepen.io/finnhvman/" target="_top">CodePen</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    Created with<br/>
    <br/>
    <a href="https://codepen.io/collection/nZKBZe/" target="_top">Pure CSS Material Components</a>
  </div>
</footer>
<template>
    <li class="item">
        <label>
            <input class="hidden" type="checkbox">
            <span class="count"></span>
            <span class="word"></span>
        </label>
    </li>
</template>
```

Comment: Какая версия Firefox у вас? Unicode Property Escapes уже поддерживаются начиная с 78: https://caniuse.com/?search=Unicode%20Property%20Escapes

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Старая, однако хотелось бы найти универсальное решение, которое будет работать на любой** версии.

Comment: По приведённой Вами-же ссылке: "Before ES2018 there was no performance-efficient way to match characters from different sets based on scripts (like Macedonian, Greek, Georgian etc.) or propertyName (like Emoji etc) in JavaScript. Check out tc39 Proposal on Unicode Property Escapes for more info." От себя добавлю, что полифил будет и большим по размеру, и медленным , и трудно сопровождаемым. На мой взгляд, Вам нужно описать проблему/задачу и решать её исходя из Ваших требований.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас старая версия Firefox, просто так универсальную замену будет найти непросто. Но для большинства случаев можно попробовать заменить эту строку:

```js
: new RegExp(`(\\w+){${minLength},}`, 'g');
```

на эту:

```js
: new RegExp(`([\\wА-Яа-яЁё]+){${minLength},}`, 'g');
```

Comment: Огромное человеческое спасибо, невероятная помощь. Без лишних слов и флуда типа "Вам нужно описать проблему/задачу и решать её исходя из Ваших требований". Невероятная помощь. БЛАГОДАРЮ!

Comment: Для того, чтоб не было, как Вы выразились, флуда, нужно задавать более качественные вопросы описывая все детали, требования, ошибки и что конкретно не работает. В следующий раз, когда Вы приведёте 100500 строк кода, сделайте милость, уделите немного времени для Вашего-же вопроса.

Comment: @XelaNimed - это связано с тем что код и есть вопрос. Что конкретно мне нужно было описать - если при нажатии на кнопку "выполнить код" (с условием открытия его через браузер фаерфокса) все становится очевидным. Прошу прощения за то что затронула ваши чувства - в другой раз постараюсь учесть ваши рекомендации.